# Diffeomorphism in a group action

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Considering the group action: $\Omega = \{ \mathbb{Z},+  \}$ on $E = \mathbb{R}^2$ and:

$$ \omega \cdot (x,y)=(x+ \omega, (-1)^{\omega} y)$$

knowing that it is a free and proper action, how can we show that $ \mathbb{R}^2\ / \Omega$ is diffeomorphic to the quocient of $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ by the action of the group with two elements given by the antipode transformation:

$$ (x,y) \longrightarrow (-x,-y)$$

and what is the manifold we obtain?

EDIT:

Writting the following diagram:
[image]

how can I justify that $\alpha$ is a diffeomorfism? If it is, then by a covering I can get to $S^1/\{+1,-1\}$ correct?

Answer (score 2):

First, we note that the quotient of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by the subgroup of *even* numbers is $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}.$ The we are left with the $\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$ action, which is easily seen to be the antipode action. You should be able to figure out which manifold is obtaied.